# HA of spark streaming application on yarn

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, hadoop-yarn, high-availability

We are running spark streaming application on yarn-cluster on a cluster that was defined using cloudera. 
We defined one of the nodes to be spark-gateway and we run the spark-submit command from this node. 
We want to test the HA of our cluster and by this we test what happens when different nodes crush(we stop them). 
We saw that when we stop the driver node, the application still continues to run but it doesn't do anything and when looking at "yarn -list" it still writes the stopped node as the driver node. When we start back the node the application returns to work and the driver node changes to another node, but this happen only when the node is back up. Shouldn't yarn change the driver to another node as soon as the driver node dies ? 
Another thing we saw that if we kill the spark-gateway node the application stops. 
How can we run the application so it won't have any one point fail-over ?